# Moving namespaces in java

Tags: java, namespaces

I have a java project with at least 500 or so files in various directories. 
Currently, it is under a package com.company.blah. Therefore, many of the source files contain statements of the form import com.company.blah.classname.something;

I now want to move the entire package to a different namespace (e.g., newspace.foo). Apart from manually changing the files (because at some locations in the source, there are absolute paths that start at the root of the namespace and hence it is not sufficient to just change the imports), is there a tool or eclipse plugin that can make this process easy?

Answer (score 2):

Any decent IDE can do this, handling the file move, the SCM move and the consequent renaming. Intellij (in particular) [would be able to do this for you](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/move-refactorings.html) (via drag/drop in the project view or similar)

Comment: NetBeans will do this too.  Select multiple files with shift-click and drag and drop into a new package ("name space").  Go get coffee.  Done.

Answer (score 0):

Any IDE has such feature. However you can do it manually too. Just rename directory and create oneliner combining `find`, `grep` and `sed` to substitute old to new package name.

Comment: This is actually a bad idea.  An IDE will actually parse your files syntactically and do a much better job of examining (and renaming) types than sed and grep.  Using Unix tools like this will be fairly error prone.

Comment: Sure IDE does this job better. I just said that this task is doable without IDE too.